# Would questions about the availability of military style obstacle course trails be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

**Do military style obstacle course trails exist in a completely forested setting and open to the general public?**

I am interested in knowing if there are any military style obstacle course trails that exist in a completely forested setting for the military, police, search and rescue, and so on, yet are open to the general public?

Ideally the course would have be to several miles/kilometers long and both natural and manmade obstacles would be incorporated together.

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: Here is a link to the question: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/15700/7995 Ken if you feel like pulling that link into your question, or a self answer feel free to flag my comment as obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

You might want mention in your question which countries you know you can (legally) visit.

Otherwise, it sounds like a good question.